# How to completely wipe all data and settings from an AWS region

Tags: amazon-web-services

currently playing with terraform and amazon CDK trying to define all the infrastructure as code using one of the tools mentioned.

Is there a way how to **reset the whole AWS region** to "factory settings"?

I can manually delete all EC2 instances, security groups, lambda functions, whatever but I'll never be sure there are any leftovers like logs and so on...

Anyone managed to do this? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [aws-nuke](https://github.com/rebuy-de/aws-nuke) to clean up all your whole AWS account, please don't forget to read the disclaimer guide first.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no provided way to "wipe everything" from an AWS Account.

You would need to loop through every service in every region, then find and delete resources.

If you do some web searching, you will find scripts that can assist.

Comment: Too bad. Thanks for the response, though! Isn't there a plan to add such feature?